# How to get element in selenium using only a reactid

Tags: selenium, reactjs

I want to click a button with the below reactid (it is unique). How to I refer it in selenium?

```
<button class="button quick-buy-btn hide-for-print" data-reactid="66">
```

Comment: Why not just use a regular id? reactid aren't always the same and also does not exist in React V15

Comment: how to do tht then?
This does not work:
driver.findElement(By.id("data-reactid=\"66\"")).click();

Comment: `<button id="buy-button" class="button quick-buy-btn hide-for-print" data-reactid="66">`

`driver.find_element_by_id('buy-button').click()` should work

Answer (score 0):

I usually use css selectors. The selector for your element should be:
`selector = "button[class=\"button.quick-buy-btn.hide-for-print\"]".`

If you are using Java, use `driver.findElement(selector).click();`.

With python, use 'driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector).click()`

Comment: Your provided css selector is incorrect, it should be `button[class=\"button quick-buy-btn hide-for-print\"]` or `button.button.quick-buy-btn.hide-for-print`. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

CSSSelectors or XPath is your best choice, on Chrome you can copy the selector by inspecting the element then right-click -> copy -> copy selector. If the driver give you trouble, use JavascripExecutor, document.queryExecutor('expression here')